# What would be the Latin title of “2001: A Space Odyssey”?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin

The two translations suggested on Vicipaedia are “2001: caeleste iter operosum” and “Anno 2001: Odysseia Caelestis”.

Personally, I would have written “Annō 2001: Odyssēa spatiālis”.

Which one is of best latinity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chief issue with *spatialis* is that it's [unattested](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=spatial) in Latin. I can understand why 18th century philosopher-scientists coined the term, but it doesn't speak to its Latinity. Even in English, though, "spatial" more often refers to something other than space.

Meanwhile, *caelestis* referring to "of the heavens" is amply attested and is the adjective used to describe where clouds, stars, and the gods reside.

Moreover, in antiquity, as far as I can tell, *Odyssea* (and its variants, like Andronicus' *Odusia*) only ever refers to the epic written by Homer, and it would take until the end of the 19th century for it to mean a long and arduous journey, [at least in English](https://www.etymonline.com/word/odyssey#etymonline_v_2504).

My vote would be for:

> Anno MMI: Iter Caeleste

This is similar to the first example, but without the *operosum* (unnecessary) and the year converted to proper Roman numerals.